# How to create argocd apps with different branches?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, kustomize

My code repository has many branches, in each branch there is kustomize/{base,overlay}kustomizations.yaml file, when I develop in the dev branch, I submit the code to the code repository, gitlab pipeline to build the image. Then argocd will start targetvision:dev app to trigger sync, so I need to create a lot of different targetvision:dev argocd app, how do I avoid creating so many apps?

i have no idea.How to create argocd apps with different branches?

Comment: why have a directory structure w/ overlays (assuming env is your overlay) when you are using branches? I dont recommend using a multiple branches as target revisions; eventually you will have even more sub trees to an existing overlay; for example "environment" may need to be broken down to "environment" and "region" eventually. Now is the time to plan for the future

Comment: Does that mean merging branches into one branch is allowed to publish? For example, dev/master is deployed in a test environment and a production environment？

Comment: it all depends on your release strategy - i consider anything in `main` a releasable entity, and it should be live